# How to query two different fields from a table, and make it appear in the same row?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. Say:

```
This is table 1
+--------+-----------------------+
| stuff  | foreing   | foreing2  |
+--------+-----------------------+
| bazzzz |       555 |       666 |
+--------+-----------------------+

This is table 2
+-----------------------+
| id_table | values     |
+-----------------------+
|      555 | Foo        |
+-----------------------+
|      666 | Bar        |
+-----------------------+
```

What I want is a SQL query that gives me a row with this info:

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| stuff  | value1    | value2    |
+--------+-----------------------+
| bazzzz | Foo       | Bar       |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

This is what I tried to do, but actually it returns two rows, which is not what I want:

```
SELECT table1.stuff,
    table2.values as value1,
    table2.values as value2
    WHERE table1.foreing = table2.id_table
    OR table1.foreing2 = table2.id_table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to match two columns with the same child table... you need to refer the child table twice...

```
Select table1.Stuff, B.Vales as Value1, C.Values as Value2
 From table1, table2 as B, table2 as C
   Where table1.foreing = B.id_table and table1.foreing2 = C.id_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall have to make inner queries like this:

```
SELECT table1.stuff,
    (select table2.values as value1 where table2.id_table=table1.foreing),
    (select table2.values as value2 where table2.id_table=table1.foreing2)
    from table1
```

Comment: Not necessarily - see The King's answer.